# Why does ths just sit there after i input a number

Tags: c

Why does this just sit there after i input a number
This code did work and then it stopped
Can anyone tell me why the terminal freezes after i put in a number
expecting 2 values and comparison
just sits stuck

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

float myNumber = 0; 
float differenceNumber = 0;
float myQuicksqrt = 0;
float myRealsqrt = 0;

float Qsqrt(float myNumber) {
        long i;
        float x2, y;
        const float threehalfs = 1.5F;
        
        x2 = myNumber * 0.5F;
        y = myNumber;
        i = * (long *) &y;
        i = 0x5f37f9df - (i >> 1);
        y = * (float *) &i;
        y = y * (threehalfs - (x2*y*y) );
        return y;
}
float largerNumber(float myRealsqrt, float myQuicksqrt) {
    float largestNumber;
    if(myQuicksqrt > myRealsqrt)
        largestNumber = myQuicksqrt;
    if(myQuicksqrt < myRealsqrt)
        largestNumber = myRealsqrt;
    if(myQuicksqrt == myRealsqrt)
        largestNumber = 0;
    return largestNumber;
}

int main() {
    for (int _i = 0; _i < 4; _i++) {
        printf("Please enter a number: ");
        scanf("%f\n", &myNumber);
        myQuicksqrt = Qsqrt(myNumber);
        myRealsqrt = (1 / sqrt(myNumber));
        printf("\n%f", myQuicksqrt);
        printf("\n%f", myRealsqrt);
        differenceNumber = largerNumber(myQuicksqrt, myRealsqrt);
        if (differenceNumber != myQuicksqrt)
            differenceNumber = (differenceNumber - myQuicksqrt);
        else if (differenceNumber != myRealsqrt)
            differenceNumber = (differenceNumber - myRealsqrt);
        else
            continue;
        printf("\n%f", differenceNumber);
        if  (differenceNumber == 0)
            printf("\nThe numbers are equal\n");
        else
            printf("\n%f\n", differenceNumber);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

expecting 2 values and comparison
just sits stuck

Comment: Note that *every* character in the `scanf` format string has a specific purpose. Also your `printf("\n%f", myQuicksqrt);` is very poor practice: place the newline *after* what you print, as `printf("%f\n", myQuicksqrt);`. You are washing the dishes before the meal, instead of after.

Comment: Pay attention to your scanf function in the main function. Having specific characters inside your scanf function can cause unexpected behavior you are seeing here.